# horizontal layout do not split in horizontal way

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to display three TextField in a line horizontally, but the components will be displayed in vertical way:

this is the code:

```
VerticalLayout vertical = new VerticalLayout();
vertical.addComponent(new TextField("Name"));
vertical.addComponent(new TextField("Street address"));
vertical.addComponent(new TextField("Postal code"));
HorizontalLayout horizontal = new HorizontalLayout();
horizontal.addComponent(new TextField("Name"));
horizontal.addComponent(new TextField("Street address"));
horizontal.addComponent(new TextField("Postal code"));

//setWidth("670px");
        
//setWidth("100%");

addComponents(vertical, horizontal);
```

when I diplay that I see:
[image]

I've tried to increase the width to 100% try to set the width to 900px; But I'm not able to figure out what can be the issue and where to look for?

Comment: Your code looks fine, it should work as you expected. Any errors in the browser console? The TextField components don't look correct either, unless you have a custom theme and you’ve made them smaller.

Comment: No errors in the browser console, but yes I use a custom theme; is there a way to prevent use the custom theme from my code? thx a lot

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to have your own look _everywhere_ or do you just need to style a few things? So you either want to add "horizontal behaviour" to _your_ theme, or start with one of the vaadin themes and change that, where you need it.

Comment: What's the type where of the class where you are doing this?

Comment: there was an error on the thema, resolved :)

Comment: Good to hear you got it resolved. Would be nice if you updated your post with the cause of the issue, so that others can learn from it.

Comment: indeed it was my mistake because in the name of the class: public class ApplicationLayout extends VerticalLayout implements View there wasn't VerticalLayout but HorizontalLayout; I know it seems strange but after that change it works :)   And also I ve changed the tema that was a custom tema, so I think there was a mistake on the tema; Sorry not able to give more details;